# como unir javascript a la pagina web?

Tags: javascript, html

quiero hacer interacciones en mi pagina web con javascript, pero no se como hacerlo, soy nuevo en esto, ya puse el respectivo codigo para unir javascript con el hmtl que es el siguiente:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="interaccion.js"></script>`

el problema es que no se como seleccionar cada elemento del html como el header por ejemplo, para usarlo en javascript y hacer las respectivamente interacciones, muchas gracias

Comment: Tu pregunta es muy amplia y puede terminar cerrada, aqui tienes [opcion 1](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) y [opcion 2](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) te recomiendo leer a detalle estos recursos, intentar algo y volver a preguntar pero con dudas un tanto mas específicas.

Comment: Podrias comenzar por [este link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_queryselector.asp)

Comment: muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Respecto a lo del header lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera :
Mediante el arbol DOM selecionamos el elemento HTML :

```
     var header = document.getElementById("{id del header}");
```

Una vez seleccionado puedes aplicar estilos sobre el ,eventos y mucho mas .